# SQL Monitoring Increase and decrease for the Quantity of a Product

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am writing a simple application in VB.net and I am stuck in one SQL statement. Lets say that I have the following tables with some sample data

**Products Table** with `attributes` , `ProductID`  `ProductName` ,  `CategoryID` , `UnitPrice`, `QuantityOnhand`

```
ProductId  Name  UnitPrice  QTYonaHand
001        XYZ   3          25
```

.  I want to track increase and decrease for  the Quantity of items that i have. those are Some of the Transactions that make The QuantityOnhand of a Product to increase or decrease.

**BillDetails Table** with attributes `BillNo` , `Productid` , `Qty` , `Price` -  represents purchases from vendors and will increase quantity

```
  BillNo   ProductId    Qty     Price
    01      001          36      3
```

**InvoiceDetails Table** with attributes `InvoiceId` ,`Productid` , `Qty` , `Price` -  represents sales to customers and will decrease quantity.

```
 InvoiceNo     ProductId        Qty    Price
    10             001          6      4
    12             001          5      4.5
```

My goal is to write a SQL statement which returns table

**ProductDetail**

For Example Product XYZ

```
Type      Date         Ref     Qty        OnHand
Bill      4/15/2017    01      36         36
Invoice   4/16/2017    10      -6         30
Invoice   4/17/2017    12      -5         25
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please show i) sample data of the input tables, ii) what you have tried so far.

Comment: How do you know the dates of the bills and invoices? They are not in your inputs, but are in your outputs.

Comment: The InvoiceDetails table have a relationship with an **Invoice table** which have attributes like 'InvoiceNo' , 'InvoiceDate' , 'CustomerId' i will get the invoiceDate there. also the same way BillDetails Table Have a relationship With **BillsTable**  which have attributes like 'BillNo' , 'BillDate' ,  'VendorId'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THIS HAVE DONE THE TRICK

```
Select BILLDATE AS DATE, 'BILL' as Type, B.BILLno as Ref,  BD.QTY  as QTY from Bill B
inner join BILLDETAILS  BD
on 
 B.BILLno = BD.[BILLno]
 where BD.ProductId = 001

UNION ALL

Select [Invoice Date] AS DATE , 'Invoice' as Type, S.[invoice no] as Ref,  D.QTY * -1 as QTY from SALESINVOICE S 
inner join SalesInvoiceDetails  D
on 
 S.[Invoice No] = D.[Invoice NO]
 where d.ProductId = 001
 ORDER BY DATE ASC
```

[image]

BUT HOW CAN I Add a Running Balance Calculation Column